# Is there any way to border entire plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a stacked bar plot with legends at location 3 i.e, "lower left" also legends are taken below x-axis with bbox_to_anchor=(0,-0.4).Current plot and required result are as follows.

[Current Plot &](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvNd0.png)
[Required result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnWFt.png)

Is there any way to border entire plot as in required result?
Legends may increase in some cases.So the border should adjust accordingly on y-axis.

Comment: show you code, or give code with test example that will show the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can set edgecolor and linewidth of the figure patch.

*Example for a black border with thickness of 1 point:*

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_edgecolor((0, 0, 0, 1.0))
fig.patch.set_linewidth(1)
```